# Study live alerts resets initialized variables, but on historical data it works well

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

Aiming to get alerts, only possible in Studies, I've created a Study from a Strategy where I purposely don't use pyramiding. Alerts are set to execute Once Per Bar Close.

Because Studies don't have pyramiding options, I've programmed in the Study a similar functionality to avoid pyramiding as follows:

1. Initialize boolean variables `Last_is_long` and `Last_is_short` to store whether the last move was a long or a short
2. Check the boolean as part of the complete `longCondition` and as part of the complete `shortCondition`
3. I make an `alertcondition()` based on such complete conditions, which include the booleans, thus

Something like:

```
//@version=4
study(title="MyStudy", shorttitle="MyStudy", overlay=true)
...
//VARIABLE INITIALIZATION:
var bool Last_is_long = false
var bool Last_is_short = false
...
longCondition = myLongCondition() and not(Last_is_long)
shortCondition = myShortCondition() and not(Last_is_short)
...
alertcondition(longCondition, title='Long', message='Long now!')
if longCondition
    label.new(time, close, text = "Long", color=color.lime, xloc = xloc.bar_time)
    Last_is_long := true
    Last_is_short := false
...
alertcondition(shortCondition, title='Short', message='Short now!')
if shortCondition
    label.new(time, close, text = "Short", color=color.red, xloc = xloc.bar_time)
    Last_is_long := false
    Last_is_short := true
```

When looking at the charts, it works perfectly. However, with an alert turned ON, it looks like `Last_is_long` and `Last_is_short` variables are always being re-initialized (to `false`, thus), as alerts are coming in every bar.

One way to fix it is re-working the entire fundamental `myLongCondition()` and `myShortCondition()` functions to avoid pyramiding somehow intrinsically, but I don't see a way not to fall again in booleans which should not be re-initialized.

Any ideas to overcome it?

Out of curiosity: is it a known and desired behaviour that Studies with alerts simply re-init variables every next execution step?

=========================================

EDIT (full script below):

```
 // Licensing information: free as bird. A referral to me would be much appreciated, though.
// Description: meant to be used with BTCUSD (or XBTUSD) on 3 mins to 1h candles charts.
// Idea is to provide a tool to detect break-out's from a dead band around an EMA, and to detect back-in's to the dead band.
// Detection is fundamentally based on how much %, at least, a certain candle body has ruptured the dead band (adjustable).
// Long and short flags are placed on the chart, as well as the deadband. Can be used to generate alers.
// With minimal modifications, can be convert to a Strategy script.

// Following are ideas to play around if you want. Room for improvements:
//  - convert constants into inputs, and diversify thresholds assimetrically
//  - play around with wether or not using pyramiding (here pyramiding is blocked)
//  - look at several bars in a sequence, not only current

// © esturilio:
//  TV  : https://www.tradingview.com/u/esturilio/
//  SO  : https://stackoverflow.com/users/12678720/glauco-esturilio?tab=profile
//  GH  : esturilio
//  TW  : @esturilio

//@version=4
study(title="Deadband cross", shorttitle="DB-X", overlay=true)

// === INIT VARIABLES === (needed on Study because Studies don't know about pyramiding)
var bool Last_is_long = false
var bool Last_is_short = false

// Defining the EMA curve for visualization
emaLen = input(12, minval=1, title="EMA Length")
emaSrc = input(open, title="Source for EMA")
emaVal = ema(emaSrc, emaLen)
plot(emaVal, title="EMA", color=color.blue)

// Defining the deadbands:
var float SigmaVar = input(0.30, minval=0, title="% deadband") // band around EMA
SigmaUp = emaVal * (1 + SigmaVar/100)
SigmaDw = emaVal * (1 - SigmaVar/100)
plot(SigmaUp, title="Band+", color=color.orange)
plot(SigmaDw, title="Band-", color=color.orange)

// Definition of the threshold for cross detection:
bar_bodypercent_threshold = input(50,title="%bar threshold for cross detection")

// =============================================================================
// detect cross or already crossed situations:
n_bar_span = abs(close - open)

// following conditions will be used to detect a bullish situation
bull_cross() => (close > SigmaUp and open < SigmaUp) or (close > SigmaUp and open > SigmaUp)
bear_back_cross() => (close > SigmaDw and open < SigmaDw)

// following conditions will be used to detect a bearish situation
bear_cross() => (close < SigmaDw and open > SigmaDw) or (close < SigmaDw and open < SigmaDw)
bull_back_cross() => (close < SigmaUp and open > SigmaUp)


// =============================================================================
// Calculate bar% above SigmaUp when crossing upwards
percent_bar_above_SigmaUp = if bull_cross()
    (100*(( max(close,open) - SigmaUp)/n_bar_span))
else
    0

// Calculate bar% below SigmaUp when crossing back down
percent_bar_below_SigmaUp = if bull_back_cross()
    (100*(( SigmaUp - min(close,open))/n_bar_span))
else
    0

// Calculate bar% below SigmaDw when crossing downwards    
percent_bar_below_SigmaDw = if bear_cross()
    (100*(( SigmaDw - min(close,open))/n_bar_span))
else
    0

// Calculate bar% above SigmaDw when crossing back up
percent_bar_above_SigmaDw = if bear_back_cross()
    (100*((max(close,open) - SigmaDw)/n_bar_span))
else
    0

// =============================================================================
// FINAL TRIGGERNIG:

 //longCondition: either bull or back from bear
longCondition  = ((close > SigmaUp) and (percent_bar_above_SigmaUp >= bar_bodypercent_threshold)) or ((close < SigmaUp) and (percent_bar_above_SigmaDw >= bar_bodypercent_threshold))

 //shortCondition: either bear or back from bull 
shortCondition = ((close < SigmaDw) and (percent_bar_below_SigmaDw >= bar_bodypercent_threshold)) or ((close > SigmaDw) and (percent_bar_below_SigmaUp >= bar_bodypercent_threshold))


longConditionFull = longCondition and Last_is_long == false
alertcondition(longConditionFull, title='LongTrigger', message='LongTrigger')

if  longConditionFull
    //if converting to strategy, you can uncomment below line for activating orders:
    //strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long)

    //plot green arrow
    label.new(time, close, text = "L", style=label.style_labelup, yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.lime, xloc = xloc.bar_time)

    //make sure pyramiding is not allowed 
    Last_is_long := true
    Last_is_short := false


shortConditionFull = shortCondition and Last_is_short == false
alertcondition(shortConditionFull, title='ShortTrigger', message='ShortTrigger')

if shortConditionFull
    //if converting to strategy, you can uncomment below line for activating orders:
    //strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short)

    //plot red arrow
    label.new(time, close, text = "S", style=label.style_labeldown, yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.red, xloc = xloc.bar_time)

    //make sure pyramiding is not allowed 
    Last_is_long := false
    Last_is_short := true

//DEBUG & PLOTTING: 
 // Bull and back from bull
//plot(percent_bar_above_SigmaUp, title="%above EMA+s",color=color.green)
//plot(percent_bar_below_SigmaUp, title="%above EMA+s",color=color.olive)

 // Bear and back from bear
//plot(percent_bar_below_SigmaDw, title="%below EMA-s",color=color.red)
//plot(percent_bar_above_SigmaDw, title="%below EMA-s",color=color.fuchsia)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code logic seems sound and alerts work fine here. Perhaps you could try validating your states at your end using debugging code like the one included here:

```
//@version=4
study(title="MyStudy", shorttitle="MyStudy", overlay=true)

//VARIABLE INITIALIZATION:
var bool Last_is_long = false
var bool Last_is_short = false

barUp = close >= open
myLongCondition() => barUp and barUp[1]
myShortCondition() => not barUp and not barUp[1]

longCondition = myLongCondition() and not(Last_is_long)
shortCondition = myShortCondition() and not(Last_is_short)

alertcondition(longCondition, title='Long', message='Long now!')
if longCondition
    label.new(time, close, text = "Long", color=color.lime, xloc = xloc.bar_time)
    Last_is_long := true
    Last_is_short := false

alertcondition(shortCondition, title='Short', message='Short now!')
if shortCondition
    label.new(time, close, text = "Short", color=color.red, xloc = xloc.bar_time)
    Last_is_long := false
    Last_is_short := true

bgcolor(Last_is_long ? color.green : Last_is_short ? color.maroon : na) 
plotchar(Last_is_long, "Last_is_long", "", location.top)
plotchar(Last_is_short, "Last_is_short", "", location.top)
plotchar(longCondition, "longCondition", "▲", location.top)
plotchar(shortCondition, "shortCondition", "▼", location.bottom)
```

As is explained in the User Manual [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html#calculation-based-on-realtime-bars), there is a resetting of variables going on in the realtime bar by means of the rollback process, but this only affects behavior in the realtime bar and does not impact alerts configured to trigger "Once Per Bar Close".

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! After debugging and reading the reference, I could proof the resetting of variables on realtime indeed is the root cause. I'll have to re-work the fundamental strategy to natively avoid pyramiding if I want it to be convertable to a study with alerts.

Comment: Oeps, just realized one thing: apparently it does affect alerts configured to trigger "Once Per Bar Close". How I tested it: I've disabled the boolean check on the so-named complete condition, that is, something the pyramiding > 1 would do in the strategy, and indeed I've got many plotted flags as well.
However: after this test I've kept receiving alerts at every bar close, even not seeing nor flags on the study nor entries on the original strategy. This is getting trickier now

Comment: Are you using `security()` at a lower resolution than the chart's? If so, that could be a cause. If not, without complete code it's impossible for us to troubleshoot.

Comment: No, not using `security()`. I've deleted the alert and reset it, and it simply worked as advertised, that is, no problems when selecting "Once Per Bar Close". I can't even reproduce it anymore. I might have set it wrongly at first time, or modified the script w/o reseting properly the alerts.

Comment: I'm editing the original question to add the full script. I'm also publishing it under the name of "Deadband cross (Public)". Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Thx for publishing open source! For others here, this is Glauco's script: https://www.tradingview.com/script/t0Fu8IF4-Deadband-cross-detection-for-BTC-XBT/